# Cleaning up file system API data

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

I'm thinking of creating a html page that will on Chrome use the [file system api](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) to store a significant amount of local data by requesting a fairly large quota.

However if the user goes to my website and runs the application and then decides they don't like it and never go back it will leave a great deal of data *somewhere* on their disk. Unlike real applications, they can't just find the data using a normal file browser in an obvious place and delete it to tidy up.

But I want to behave as a decent citizen and not leave huge amounts of data stuck on someones disk if they didn't like my application.

What is the best way to manage this data or to allow a user to tidy up the data given that they might never go back to the site and might not ever know the data is there as it's not in an obvious disk location?